# Getting name of field that is primary_key

Tags: python, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

Using Python I do:

```
r.table_create('examples', primary_key='name')
```

Now how do I get the name of the primary_key field which is "name"? I tried:

```
r.table('examples').index_list().run()
```

But it only returns secondary indexes.

Comment: What python framework do you use for sql? And also what databse is behind it?

Comment: I'm using NoSql database: RethinkDb and their builtin Python wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `r.table('test').info().run()` part of the output is the primary key.